# C# do something before setting variable

Tags: c#

I have certain class variables in a class that I would like to do somethin whenever they are set (check valid, pad with spaces etc).  I have never used get set before was wondering if using those would be right approach but I am getting stack overflow error.

```
    public string DELIVERY_DATE
    {
        get { return DELIVERY_DATE; }
        set 
        {
            DELIVERY_DATE = checkDate(value, "yyyyMMdd");
        }
    }
```

Comment: `DELIVERY_DATE` is a property. You need a backing field (i.e., a variable) to use in the setter and getter. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties) for reference.

Comment: You're setting the variable in the setter for the variable, resulting in infinite recursion... Use a separate var for the value.

Comment: Also you should really be using standard C# naming conventions. For your enjoyment https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions

Comment: Setters and getters are just methods that are generated by the compiler, you can do anything in them you like, ideally you would not want to do anything heavy (or asynchronous work), however a small validation or mutation is fine. As to where these lines are and how much validation (such as throwing) is best practice is opinionated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a recursion here. Delivery date calls itself. try this

```
private string _DELIVERY_DATE
public string DELIVERY_DATE
   {
       get { return _DELIVERY_DATE; }
       set 
       {
           _DELIVERY_DATE = checkDate(value, "yyyyMMdd");
       }
   }
```

Comment: Is this a good method to do some routine before setting the variable though?

Comment: @bakalolo  Yes, usually it is using for validation. The code should be as clouse to data it validates as possible. This is the most closed. For example you can check if delivery date should be in the future (or past) and  fixed it or set to null or set it as error (since it is a string).

Answer (score 0):

Properties are valid way to do this. But you use it inappropriately:

```cs
class myClass {

   // here will be stored the value
   private string deliveryDate;
   public string DELIVERY_DATE
   {
      // this "method" will be called 
      // when e.g. x = thisClass.DELIVERY_DATE line executed
      get 
      { 
         return deliveryDate; 
      }
      // this "method" will be called 
      // when e.g. thisclass.DELIVERY_DATE = "20211108" executed
      set 
      {
         deliveryDate = checkDate(value, "yyyyMMdd");
      }
   }

}
```

Here are MS docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties